# TimerTask is already scheduled

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, timertask

I have a `MediaPlayer` object which plays a local audio file. I am using a `TimerTask` to update the position of a SeekBar and text on a TextView while the audio plays.

There is one button. When the user presses the button audio starts. When they press it a second time the audio stops. When they press it a third time to begin playback again the app crashes with the error

```
'causedby: TimerTask is scheduled already and InvocationTargetException'.
```

Here is my code:

```
    public void onAudioClicked(View v) {
    if (mainPlayer == null) {
        mainPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.session1);
        // Get audio duration and set textview
        int d = mainPlayer.getDuration();
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalTime);
        t.setText(String.format("%d:%d", 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(d),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(d) - 
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(d))));

        sb.setProgress(0);
        sb.setMax(mainPlayer.getDuration());
        mainPlayer.start();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, 1000);
    } else {
        mainPlayer.stop();
        mainPlayer.release();
        mainPlayer = null;
        timer.cancel();
        task.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
    public void run(){
        int currentPosition = 0;
        int total = mainPlayer.getDuration();
        sb.setMax(total);
        while (mainPlayer != null && currentPosition < total) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                currentPosition = mainPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                runOnUiThread(updateControlsRunnable);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }
            sb.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }

    }
};

final Runnable updateControlsRunnable = new Runnable () {
    public void run(){
        int d = mainPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.currentTime);
        t.setText(String.format("%d:%d", 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(d),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(d) - 
                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(d))));
        }
};
```

Comment: are you using the `timer` variable, somewhere in other method to for same purpose ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code block please:

```
sb.setProgress(0);
sb.setMax(mainPlayer.getDuration());
mainPlayer.start();
timer = new Timer();
MyTask task=new MyTask();
timer.schedule(task,0, 1000);

private class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        //Your code...
    }
}
```